# How to get array value and input to text() with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have the following code:

Array part:

```
var menu = 
    [
        {
            td: {'id': 'td_1'},
            a:  {'class': 'td_class', 'id': 'td_id_1'},
            p:  {'title': 'TD1', 'style': 'color:#fff;'}
        },
        {
            td: {'id': 'td_2'},
            a:  {'class': 'td_class_2', 'id': 'td_id_2'},
            p:  {'title': 'TD2', 'style': 'color:#fff;'}
        }
    ];
```

and rest of the js code:

```
 $.each(menu, function(i, item){
        $('<td>').attr('id', item.td.id)
                .append($('<a>', {'class': item.a.class, 'id': item.a.id})
                .append($('<p>', {'text': item.p.title, 'style': item.p.style})))
                .insertBefore('#menu');
    });
```

HTML part:

```
<div class="block02">
   <h1 id="h1" style="color:#fff;"></h1>
</div>
<td id="menu"></td>
```

I want to add text from array and insert into h1:

```
if ($('#td_1').hasClass('td_class')){
        $('.block02 h1').text(td.p.title);
    }
} else ....
```

Of course I get nothing. My question is: How to get "TD1" as h1's text value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to traverse to paragraph `p` element in `td`, then get its text.

*Use*

```
$('.block02 h1').text($('#td_1.td_class > p').text());
```